# Is there Single tier Architecture for web based applications?

Tags: c#, architecture

Can anyone give any examples of a single tier architecture that is web-based?  I understand that single tier means that all layers are run in the same machine... Would a soap service that returns a number from a database be an example or is that two tiered?

Comment: This is very general question:) Maybe you have something more specific?

Answer (score 3):

> Would a soap service that returns a number from a database be an example or is that two tiered?

Using a database back-end is a two-tier architecture.  Another example is the old-school ASP-style of development where the .asp file directly accesses the database.

> Can anyone give any examples of a single tier architecture that is web-based?

A single-tier might be a webpage that directly opens a csv file and reads from it.  Another example is a web-service that does not require data at all, like a time service.

Answer (score 1):

Actually **there is no** Single tier web application.
 Yes I insist :)

Because the Web Browser and the client machine is actually a tier.

But to make things easy the community assumes to drop this tire due to it's out of developer hands.

Anyway if you consider that any web page which is not dealing with database **OR in better way like csharptest.net said :**

> A single-tier might be a webpage that directly opens a csv file and reads from it. Another example is a web-service that does not require data at all, like a time service

You may consider that as Single tier

Comment: The interesting thing about tiers and layer are the abstraction level, that we are talking about. Firstly you dropped the browser/http tier. The you assume file as first-order entity - but file itself could be a stream (that is on a pipeline with some IO/networking devices), or it could be mediator storage between some processes. So, from my side, the count of layers is question of abstraction level you introduce :)

Comment: Including the browser is a fair comment/correction given the prevalence of client-side scripting.

Comment: @csharptest-net So you agree with me "There is no Single tier web application" ?

Comment: @ajukraine Yes you're right :)

Comment: @Wahid Bitar I agree in that saying "There is no Single tier web application" is a matter for debate.  Old-timers like me don't consider the client, and from a 'server architecture' point-of-view it's not.  Yet with many of today's applications including client script it's hard to completely disregard the browser.  Still, provided that you omit client scripting, I would call it a single-tier.  It's a single tier that produces the display format (html), the business rules, and data access (if any).  Here I am assuming the html output is no different than directly rendering to screen or image.